Regex match for character class and new line or end of data
I need an regular expression to match every line in a file with = followed by new-line or A or B or C.
For example, I want the search to give me
They're Coming=
and
Pipeline=A
but not
#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQNI1KfGXBA
I'm using NotePad++ regex match to do the search. How can I do this?

Does Pipeline=AZ qualify?

You may search for the following pattern:
^.*=[ABC]?$

Please run the above regex search with dot all mode disabled.  This is to ensure that the .* does not match across lines.

The .* would be greedy, no?

^ is redundant.

If the goal is to match the whole line with the goal of deleting it, you would use .*=[ABC]?\n. including the newline would mean replacing it with blank will delete the line. Without the newline in the regex, you'd leave a blank line behind. To insure against the last line of the file matching, but not having a newline .*=[ABC]?(\n\Z)

@Bohemian Better to match on \R to capture all potential line endings.

@tim does notepad respect \R?

Tim's answer is hard to beat.
Assuming nothing except the end of line is to match the A, B, or C part.
To capture just the tail
(=A$)|(=B$)|(=C$)|(=$)

To capture the entire line:
.*((=A$)|(=B$)|(=C$)|(=$))


.*(=A$)|(=B$)|(=C$)|(=$) can be simplified while maintaining the intention to .*=(A|B|C|)$. Regardless, your inner brackets are redundant - ie at least simplify to .*(=A$|=B$|=C$|=$)
